# Why couldn't Eren Yeager transform into a Titan in the last episode of season 2?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the last episode of season 2, named "Scream", Eren Yeager was unable to transform into a Titan to save Hannes from the Smiling Titan.

Why couldn't he transform?

I don't really read the manga, although I do look at it from time to time.

Has there already been an explanation for this in the manga?

Comment: from what I remembered he was too tired from previous transformations and cloud not do it until properly rested.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Power of the Titans](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_the_Titans) wiki (**disclamer, this page contains heavy spoilers from the manga)**, the ability to transform into a titan may be hindered if an injury occurred after a recent transformation.

> The ability to transform into a Titan can be hindered by injuries inflicted on the human body. A human can transform into a Titan with injuries as severe as a missing limb, but only if a previous transformation has not occurred recently. **If a human emerges from their Titan form and receives severe injury, this person cannot transform into a Titan again until said injuries have healed**

In the episodes leading up to this event

> We see Eren face off with the Armored Titan, but ends up being captured along with Ymir. They soon awaken with their arms severed off to prevent from the escaping.

and in [S2, E9](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Opening_(Episode))

> *Reiner informs the two that neither of them could transform into Titans in the first place while still recovering from their injuries*

When Eren attempted to transform in the final episode, his body was still recovering from this injury inflicted on him.

Answer (score 2):

Eren was still recovering from his previous fight, therefore all of his energy was still going into his regeneration.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site related to anime & manga! While your answer might be correct, it'd be better if it could be backed up with official sources/references, like from which episode/chapter this is mentioned. You can always [edit] your post to improve it. Meanwhile, consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an upper limit to how much time and energy you can spend in the transformation. And not to mention his exhaustion from the previous fights.

Comment: Could you provide source/references to back up this answer?

Comment: @AkiTanaka yeah in anime, when Bertholdt and Reiner are running away, I think Reiner mentions that. It is also referenced in the Clash of the Titan arc (the fight on the wall, where Bertholdt has an incomplete transformation due to exhaustion).